# Too many redirects issue in local host (IIS,ColdFusion 2018)

Tags: redirect, iis, coldfusion-2018

I am setting up ColdFusion 2018 Application server with IIS 10. But getting too many redirects issue. 
I have tried from square one.. Below are the things I did.

1. Installed CF 2018 developer
2. Configure IIS (Windows 10) with CF 2018 using wsconfig.
3. Created a simple “index.cfm” and tried to access. This page contains just cfset and cfoutput.
4. got 404 error.
5. updated “enable 32-bit applications” to false in IIS application pool
6. 404 error resolved, but getting “**Too Many redirects issue**”
7. enabled developer tools in IE and checked.
8. getting 302 status code and it seems index.cfm is redirecting to itself.

Not sure what to do now? Is there anything I missed in setting up IIS with CF 2018 server?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this error by making sure that the two required components of IIS are installed on your system. Namely:

- ISAPI Extensions
- IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility.

First, start the program called Windows Features. You will find Windows Features under Control Panel –> Programs and Features.

When the Windows Features starts, navigate through the features hierarchy under Internet Information Services and select the two features:

(a) ISAPI extensions and

(b) IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility.

[image]

Configuring IIS for ColdFusion:

You will have to run the Web Server Configuration Tool that comes with ColdFusion to configure IIS so that all .CFM files are mapped to be handled by ColdFusion.

The following text is directly from the ColdFusion installation guide:

1)Start the Web Server Configuration Tool by selecting Start > Programs > Adobe > ColdFusion 9 > Web Server Configuration Tool.

2)Click Add.

3)In the Server pop-up menu, select the host name and the server or cluster name to configure. In the ColdFusion server configuration, the server name is always coldfusion. Clustering support is not available on the server configuration.

Note: The server or cluster does not have to reside on the web server computer.

[image]

4)In the Web Server Properties area, select IIS and specify the website. For IIS, you typically specify All.

5)Select the Configure web server for ColdFusion applications option, and click OK.

[image]

Note: Omitting the previous step causes your web server to serve ColdFusion source code.

6)Copy the CFIDE and cfdocs directories from cf_root/wwwroot to your web server root directory. In addition, copy your application’s CFM pages from cf_root/wwwroot to your web server root directory. In the multiserver configuration, these files are under the jrun_root/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war directory.

if you face too **many redirects** then just **enable 32-bit applications to true**.

refer this link:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/strange-iis-redirect-issues-leads-to-jakarta-isapi-redirect-dll/td-p/4239297?page=1